# Shiny downloadButton for ggplot2 on mobile

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm having issues using downloadButton on mobile (iOS), but no issues on desktop. Here is the server code:

```
output$npsDown <- downloadHandler(
filename =  function() {
paste("BL", npsPlayerID(), "S", sep="")
},
content = function(file) {

#PLOT STUFF HERE

ggsave(file, plot = plot, device = "jpeg")

dev.off()

 } 
)
```

and here is the UI code:

```
downloadButton(outputId = "npsDown", label = "Download Chart")
```

When I click the download button on desktop, the plot downloads perfectly. But when I try to do it on mobile (iOS) this happens: [weird code from download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCr7a.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the add `contentType = 'image/png'` to your `downloadHandler`.

```
output$npsDown <- downloadHandler(
filename =  function() {
paste("BL", npsPlayerID(), "S", sep="")
},
content = function(file) {

#PLOT STUFF HERE

ggsave(file, plot = plot, device = "jpeg")

dev.off()

 },
  contentType = 'image/png'
)
```